# Cортировка по дню рождения от текущей даты js

Tags: javascript, дата

```
const arr = [
    { birthday: "1993-04-24", id: 1 },
    { birthday: "1993-08-6", id: 2 },
    { birthday: "1993-11-24", id: 3 },
    { birthday: "1993-1-24", id: 4 }, 
    { birthday: "1993-01-01", id: 5 },
  ];
```

Как я могу отсортировать этот массив по элементу даты в порядке от даты, ближайшей к текущей дате и времени?
Помогите. буду очень благодарен!

спасибо, но от текущей даты.
сегодня 2022-09-30 тобишь что-ты получалось:

```
const arr = [ 
         { birthday: "1993-11-24", id: 3 }, 
         { birthday: "1993-01-01", id: 5 }, 
         { birthday: "1993-01-24", id: 1 }, 
         { birthday: "1993-04-24", id: 4 }, 
         { birthday: "1993-08-06", id: 2 }, 
    ];
```

Comment: Вы внятно можете написать вопрос без ошибок и опечаток?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня сработало вот так:

```
const arr = [
  { birthday: "1993-04-24", id: 1 },
  { birthday: "1993-08-06", id: 2 },
  { birthday: "1993-11-24", id: 3 },
  { birthday: "1993-01-24", id: 4 }, 
  { birthday: "1993-01-01", id: 5 },
];

const dateToYMD = (date) => {
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
    return "" + (m <= 9 ? "0" + m : m) + "-" + (d <= 9 ? "0" + d : d);
  }

arr.sort((a, b) =>
            dateToYMD(new Date(a.birthday)) >
            dateToYMD(new Date(b.birthday)) >
            0
              ? 1
              : -1
          )
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [
  { birthday: "1993-04-24", id: 1 },
  { birthday: "1993-08-06", id: 2 },
  { birthday: "1993-11-24", id: 3 },
  { birthday: "1993-01-24", id: 4 }, 
  { birthday: "1993-01-01", id: 5 },
];
  
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return new Date(b.birthday) - new Date(a.birthday);
});

console.log(arr.map(i => i.birthday));

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return new Date(a.birthday) - new Date(b.birthday);
});

console.log(arr.map(i => i.birthday));
```

Так же гуглится за 5 секунд:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/how-to-sort-an-object-array-by-date-property

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52287060/how-to-sort-array-by-date-in-javascript

Вот на местном:

[Как сделать сортировку массива по дате?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/881741/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5)

[Не могу корректно отсортировать дату в массиве JS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1226433/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5-js)

[Как работает функция sort с датой?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1415787/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-sort-%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9/1415926#1415926)

Comment: спасибо, но от текущей даты. сегодня 2022-09-30 тобишь что-ты получалось: const arr = [
  { birthday: "1993-11-24", id: 3 },
  { birthday: "1993-01-01", id: 5 },
  { birthday: "1993-01-24", id: 1 },
  { birthday: "1993-04-24", id: 4 }, 
  { birthday: "1993-08-06", id: 2 },
];